# iPhone simulator hangs every other time I run

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Every other time I run any of my apps in the iOS simulator it crashes (what seems to be every other time, give or take). It crashes in main() at

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([SMAppDelegate class]));
```

With the message "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".

If I press stop button then run button again, it will launch just fine. Doesn't seem to happen on my machine at home. Is there anything that I can adjust or change?

I've tried resetting the simulator using the menu command as well as blowing the app away on the simulator device as well as deleting it out of the Applictions directory under the simulator's home directory.

XCode 4.6.2. Simulator is running iOS 6.1/ Apps are compiled for various iOS versions.

Comment: This happens to me occasionally.  Have not seen any real pattern, except that it seems more likely if the simulator is still "jiggling" after I deleted the app.  Of course, add an exception breakpoint, et al, to catch errors during startup.

Comment: The exception throw breakpoint never leaves my list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Xcode 4.6.3, which has a fix for this exact problem on OS X 10.8.4.